# Specifying the colour scale for maps in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having difficulty setting the colour scales for maps in ggplot. I need greyscale. Very grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong.  I also wonder if there is a more efficient way of getting the colour variable into ggplot (i.e. than by attaching it to 'fortified' data)?

```
library(ggplot2)
states <- map_data("state")
var <- data.frame(table(states$region)) # using rows as a dummy variable
states$variable <- var$Freq[match(states$region,var$Var1)]

map <- ggplot(states, aes(x=long, y=lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group, fill=variable), col=NA,lwd=0)

map + scale_colour_gradient(low='white', high='grey20')
map + scale_colour_grey()
```

[image]

Comment: If it's helpful I have a package in the works that makes ggplot maps with one function, assuming you already fortified the data.  You can install by ```devtools::install_github("mapping", "jaredlander")```.  Here's the GitHub page: https://github.com/jaredlander/mapping

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `scale_fill_*` and not `scale_color_*`. For the polygon geometry the fill color of the polygons is coupled to the `fill` aesthetic, not to the `color` aesthetic. In general, the function used to change the details of a particular scale is `scale_`aesthetic_name`_`type_of_scale, e.g. `scale_fill_gradient`.

Comment: I thought so too, but I'm getting `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale` with that.

Comment: You need to use a continuous scale, e.g. `scale_fill_gradient`.

Answer (score 6):

This code works for me.

```
library(ggplot2)
states <- map_data("state")
var <- data.frame(table(states$region))
states$variable <- var$Freq[match(states$region,var$Var1)]
map <- ggplot(states, aes(x=long, y=lat,fill=variable,group=group)) + geom_polygon()
map + scale_fill_gradient(low='white', high='grey20')
```

An easy way to handle problems with discrete variables is to create a "fake" continuous palette using the color palette function. See the below example.

Define color palette, here I used the hex codes for black and white but you can use any colors

```
gs.pal <- colorRampPalette(c("#FFFFFF","#000000"),bias=.1,space="rgb")
```

Now create some fake data

```
x <- rnorm(100)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x))
dat$fac <- as.factor(sort(rep(1:5,20)))
dat$y <- x * as.numeric(dat$fac)
```

Next plot it with the ggplot function `scale_*`type `_manual` in this case since its color
in you'd use `scale_colour_manual` but above you'd use `scale_fill_manual`

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=fac))+geom_point()+scale_colour_manual(values=gs.pal(5))
```

Comment: What if you use `scale_colour_brewer()` function?